# Changing a single link style not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

So I have this bit of CSS to change a specific link on a page to a different color (the default link color is the same background color of where the text is sitting, making it invisible).

```
.scroll a:link {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #5a4a31;
}

.scroll a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #5a4a31;
}

.scroll a:visisted {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #5a4a31;
}

.scroll a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #5a4a31;
}
```

Which works in every browser but Chrome ('hover' is the only part that actually works when viewing in Chrome, the rest just go to the default link styles I have set).  Anyone know why?  Thanks!!

Comment: You misspelled 'visited'.

Comment: @AndyHoffman nice catch, thanks, still doesn't work in Chrome though!

Comment: Check out my answer. Tested in Chrome. You needed to use LVHA (love/hate) ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going style each state of the link, the order you should do this is LVHA (link, visited, hover, active). Also, you misspelled 'visited'.

```
.scroll a:link {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: red;
}

.scroll a:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: green;
}

.scroll a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}

.scroll a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: orange;
}
```

You could refactor a little:

```
.scroll a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.scroll a:link { /* color: blah; */ }
.scroll a:visited { /* color: blah; */ } 
.scroll a:hover { /* color: blah; */ }
.scroll a:active { /* color: blah; */ }
```

http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/WwKzdN

Comment: Thanks, on both counts!

Answer (score 0):

1. You spelled visisted instead of visited.
2. if .scroll is the class of the link than their is no need to put
   a:link... you can just put .scroll:link or .scroll:hover.